# More efficient way than gsub twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have an array of strings:

```
orders = ["#1174.2", "#1176.3", "#1177.2", "#1178.1", "#1180.1"]
```

I am doing this to remove the leading "#" and trailing ".1"

```
orders.each do |numbers|
  puts numbers.gsub!("#", "").gsub!(/\.[0-9]/, "")
end
# returns 1174, 1176 etc..
```

The trailing ".1" could be any number to 9.. is there a better/faster way to do this?

Comment: Also, FWIW, you would probably want to use gsub, not gsub! for your example. The bang methods usually don't chain nicely, as it only returns the string if substitutions were performed - could lead to subtle bugs. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub

Comment: Will the numbers always have the same format, i.e., four digits, a decimal, and a single digit?

Comment: Are you expecting the numbers to be rounded correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cleaned_orders = orders.map { |numbers| numbers.gsub(/(^#|\.\d$)/, '') }
```

`cleaned_orders` now contains: `['1174', '1176', '1177', '1178', '1180']`

`(^#|\.\d$)` matches # if it is at the beginning of the string or a single period followed by a single digit at the end of the string.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this:

```
orders.map { |s| s.sub('#','').to_i }
#=> [1174, 1176, 1177, 1178, 1180]
```

add `to_s` in the block if you want strings.

---

In case the OP wants the numbers rounded. e.g. `#1174.8` returns `1175` etc. Then this should do the trick:

```
orders = ["#1174.2", "#1176.5", "#1177.2", "#1178.7", "#1180.1"]
#=> ["#1174.2", "#1176.5", "#1177.2", "#1178.7", "#1180.1"]     

orders.map { |s| s.sub('#','').to_f.round.to_s }
#=> ["1174", "1177", "1177", "1179", "1180"]
```

Comment: How does it not deal with the trailing period and number?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use:

```
orders = ["#1174.2", "#1176.3", "#1177.2", "#1178.1", "#1180.1"]
orders.map{ |n| n[/\d+/] } # => ["1174", "1176", "1177", "1178", "1180"]
```

`/\d+/` will return the first group of digits found, which means that `'#'` and `.n` will be ignored automatically.

Here's a benchmark:

```
require 'fruity'

orders = ["#1174.2", "#1176.3", "#1177.2", "#1178.1", "#1180.1"]

compare do
 ttm { orders.map{ |n| n[/\d+/] } }
 ursus { orders.map { |item| item.gsub(/#(\d+)(\.\d)?/, '\1') } }
 dinesh { orders.join.gsub(/\.[0-9]#/, "#").gsub(/\.[0-9]/, "").split("#") - [""] }
 sagarpandya82 { orders.map { |s| s.sub('#','').to_i.to_s } }
 infused { orders.map { |numbers| numbers.gsub(/(^#|\.\d$)/, '') } }
end

# >> Running each test 1024 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> ttm is faster than sagarpandya82 by 60.00000000000001% ± 10.0%
# >> sagarpandya82 is faster than dinesh by 2.0x ± 0.1
# >> dinesh is faster than infused by 39.99999999999999% ± 10.0%
# >> infused is faster than ursus by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
```

Comment: This is clearly the best regex among those suggested. As well as being the simplest, it reads best: as you say (sic), "return the first string of digits found".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all the numbers have four digits. If that is always true you might want to try this:

```
orders = ["#1174.2", "#1176.3", "#1177.2", "#1178.1", "#1180.1"]
orders.map { |n| n[1..-3] }
#=> ["1174","1176","1177","1178","1180"]
```

This obviously works only if all numbers have the same format and length, but it is way faster than using a regexp.

Answer (score 1):

```
orders.map { |s| s[1..-1].to_i.to_s }
  #=> ["1174", "1176", "1177", "1178", "1180"]
```

Remove `.to_s` if you want an array of integers rather than an array of strings.

Comment: Problem with `to_i` is that it won't round correctly e.g. `1774.6.to_i` will give `1774` but we probably really want `1775`. Only just noticed this and edited my answer. Although the OP (nor any other answers) mention/account for this, surely this must be the correct approach?

Comment: @sagarpandya82, we can't say. When I file my taxes, for example, our tax people round down some amounts to the nearest dollar. Todd did say truncation is desired ("The trailing ".1" could be any number to 9.")

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
orders.map { |item| item.gsub(/#(\d+)(\.\d)?/, '\1') }
 => ["1174", "1176", "1177", "1178", "1180"]
```

This works even if some elements doesn't have a dot something end.

Answer (score -2):

Use this

```
orders.join.gsub(/\.[0-9]#/, "#").gsub(/\.[0-9]/, "").split("#") - [""]
```

Returns

```
=> ["1174", "1176", "1177", "1178", "1180"]
```

**BreakDown**

This method takes 5 steps. This is irrespective of how much elements you have in array.

```
2.2.5 :019 > orders.join
 => "#1174.2#1176.3#1177.2#1178.1#1180.1" 
2.2.5 :020 > orders.join.gsub(/\.[0-9]#/, "#")
 => "#1174#1176#1177#1178#1180.1" 
2.2.5 :021 > orders.join.gsub(/\.[0-9]#/, "#").gsub(/\.[0-9]/, "")
 => "#1174#1176#1177#1178#1180" 
2.2.5 :022 > orders.join.gsub(/\.[0-9]#/, "#").gsub(/\.[0-9]/, "").split("#")
 => ["", "1174", "1176", "1177", "1178", "1180"] 
2.2.5 :023 > orders.join.gsub(/\.[0-9]#/, "#").gsub(/\.[0-9]/, "").split("#") - [""]
 => ["1174", "1176", "1177", "1178", "1180"]
```

Comment: It's a bit complex for the task.

Comment: Yea this is more complex than my original string of methods

Comment: @Toddt Yes it is complex but this is an attempt to get faster result

Comment: @Toddt I don't understand why people are downvoting this when this gives expected result. And OP asked for faster way so this is an attempt to get faster result.